# Failed to claim interface 0: Device or resource busy

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webusb

I am trying to communicate with usb device using `WEBUSB API`. BUT when I am trying to claim Interface it shows

> "DOMException: Unable to claim interface"

the `bConfigurationvalue` is `1` and interface number is `0`. I am adding the output of command `lsusb -v` below

```
~$ lsusb -v
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0930:6544 Toshiba Corp. TransMemory-Mini / Kingston DataTraveler 2.0 Stick (2GB)
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0930 Toshiba Corp.
  idProduct          0x6544 TransMemory-Mini / Kingston DataTraveler 2.0 Stick (2GB)
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 TOSHIBA 
  iProduct                2 TransMemory     
  iSerial                 3 C412F52D6C84CFC0A0012AEF
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           32
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              200mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval             255
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval             255
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

Why does it shows the device or resources busy. How to claim the interface?.

Comment: Added code indentation you should try to make your question readable with formatting tools take some time to read the [docs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The device is shown as busy because this is a USB Mass Storage class device and Linux will automatically load a kernel driver when it is connected that claims interface 0.

You can [manually unbind the USB device driver](https://lwn.net/Articles/143397/) with the following command:

`echo -n "1-1:1.0" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb-storage/unbind`

"1-1:1.0" specifies the device and interface that the usb-storage driver should unbind from. "1-1" means bus 1, port 1 and "1.0" means configuration 1, interface 0. This information is printed in the kernel log when the device is connected like this,

`usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected`

The bus and port number for your device will likely differ.

While this should allow you to use this device with WebUSB it is not likely useful as a long term solution because of the manual steps involved. WebUSB is designed for devices without built-in operating system drivers.

Comment: the command you propose will not work like that actually. You will need to do something like... sudo sh -c 'echo -n "1-1:1.0" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb-storage/unbind'

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with a device and found the `usb_modeswitch` command useful. Given the vendor and product id the device can be reset. E.g.:

```
usb_modeswitch -v 0x1d50 -p 0x60e3 --reset-usb
```