# Prevent cdc-acm driver from loading device

Tags: serial-port, webusb

I'm trying to connect a serial device with Webusb, under linux.

I have been able to list the device and open it, but I can't claim the interface. Chrome complains that the device is busy, and to fix that I need to unregister the CDC-ACM driver.

Is there a way to prevent the CDC-ACM driver from loading the device, without changes on the destkop? maybe I can change the USB descriptors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can change the device descriptors then modify the protocol, class and sub-class reported by the CDC-ACM interface so that it is marked as vendor-specific (0xff). The CDC-ACM driver will no longer recognize the interface and bind to it.

Just for completeness, if you could make changes to the desktop then you can either blacklist the usb-serial driver entirely in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist` or you could write a udev rule which runs for that device in particular (recognized be either bus path or vendor and product ID) and executes a script to [unbind the driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47695160/failed-to-claim-interface-0-device-or-resource-busy/47724582#47724582).

Comment: the linux usb gadget  driver doesn't allow me to change interface specific descriptors. I can change device descriptors, for example lsusb reports that bDeviceClass  is ` 0 (Defined at Interface level)`, but then another serial port on the same interface would stop working. Udev could be an option though

Comment: Given the number of people asking about this I should really look into patching the Linux serial gadget driver to allow this.